# Inserting user input into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects containing information on users postcode, place and collection dates. I want to be able to insert a new postcode for new registered users. At the minute my code searches through the object array to see if the postcode already exists, if it does the user is notified it is already registered. This works fine. Can someone help me to add a new postcode to the object array? I have attempted it, as you can see below but it's not working. Thanks.

```
var postcodes =
        [
            { postcode: "BT486AA1", place: "Londonderry Park, Londonderry", dates: ["16/05/2014", "18/06/2014", "19/07/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT486AB1", place: "Londonderry Park, Londonderry", dates: ["17/05/2014", "11/06/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT486AD1", place: "Londonderry Park, Londonderry", dates: ["14/05/2014", "20/06/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT486EL1", place: "Londonderry Park, Londonderry", dates: ["16/05/2014", "18/06/2014", "19/07/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT171JR6", place: "Londonderry Park, Londonderry", dates: ["17/05/2014", "11/06/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT171JR7", place: "Ballyregan Park, Londonderry", dates: ["14/05/2014", "20/06/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT171JR1", place: "Ballyregan Park,Londonderry", dates: ["16/05/2014", "18/06/2014", "19/07/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT171JR2", place: "Ballyregan Park, Londonderry", dates: ["17/05/2014", "11/06/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT181JR3", place: "Ormeau Park, Londonderry", dates: ["14/05/2014", "20/06/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT181JR4", place: "Ormeau Park, Londonderry", dates: ["16/05/2014", "18/06/2014", "19/07/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT191JR6", place: "Main Street, Londonderry", dates: ["17/05/2014", "11/06/2014"] },
            { postcode: "BT191JR7", place: "Main Street, Londonderry", dates: ["14/05/2014", "20/06/2014"] }
        ];


function RegisterUser() {

    for (var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
        var postCode = document.getElementById("pc2").value;

        if (postcodes[i].postcode === postCode) {
            alert("The postcode you entered is already registered");
        }
        else {
            AddUser();
        }


    }
}


function AddUser() {

    var postCode2 = document.getElementById("pc2").value
    var newUser = postcodes[i].postcode;

    for (var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
            if (newUser.indexOf(postCode2) === -1) {
                postcodes[i].postcode.push(postCode2);


                alert("Postcode Registered : " + postCode2 + " Smart Waste Management Scheme will be in contact regarding your step towards smart waste");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: postcodes[i].postcode under function AddUser() that is assigned to the newUser variable will not work. "i" is not assigned a value.

Comment: I would try simply creating a new object within AddUser() and push that object to the array.

Comment: You just needed to pass your newUser as a parameter. I added the code in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually simpler than you are making it.  You want something more like:

```
postcodes.push({postcode: postCode2, place: "Some place, etc." }); // plus any other properties you may be adding
```

In context, it looks like this:

```
function AddUser() {
    var postCode2 = document.getElementById("pc2").value
    var newUser = postcodes[i].postcode;

    for (var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
            if (newUser.indexOf(postCode2) === -1) {
                postcodes.push({postcode: postCode2});
                alert("Postcode Registered : " + postCode2 + " Smart Waste Management Scheme will be in contact regarding your step towards smart waste");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Great that worked, thank you. Can you tell me why the alert keeps appearing? How do I exit out of the loop when the alert appears once?

Comment: add a `break;` after the alert

Comment: He wants to push the new user to the existing post code. You are creating a whole new user. HE needs to concatenate the string with the new user postcode. Not a whole new user.

Comment: I do want to create a whole new user- within the postcodes object array?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can insert another object into the array:

```
function AddUser() {
  postcodes.push(
    { postcode: "BT191JR7", place: "Main Street, Londonderry", dates: ["14/05/2014", "20/06/2014"] }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not want a whole new user. Looks like you just want to add a post code to an existing object in your postcodes. 
Adding a whole new object will not allow you to just add to the existing postcode.

This code allows you to use one object and add the new user to the existing postcode.

```
function RegisterUser() {

    for (var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
        var postCode = document.getElementById("pc2").value;
        var passPostcode = postcodes[i].postcode;

        if (passPostcode === postCode) {
            alert("The postcode you entered is already registered");
            break;
        }
        else {
            AddUser(passPostcode);
        }


   }
}


function AddUser(newUser) {

    var postCode2 = document.getElementById("pc2").value
    this.newUser = newUser;

    for (var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
        if (this.newUser.indexOf(postCode2) === -1) {
            var str_postcode = postcodes[i].postcode;
            var addedNewPostCodeToString = str_postcode + ',' + postCode2;
            //postcodes[i].postcode is not an array. Push will not work. You will need to concatenate the string and will need to add a delimiter 
            postcodes[i].postcode = addedNewPostCodeToString; //delimited with comma. 


            alert("Postcode Registered : " + postCode2 + " Smart Waste Management Scheme will be in contact regarding your step towards smart waste");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I stand corrected. I see he was asking for a new user. I am going to leave this code up as reference.

Comment: I am slightly confused by this, I am relatively new to javasrcipt so bear with me. What I want is for a user to enter their postcode and if it is not in the object array then I want them to be added into it as a new user, therefore different to any other objects in the array.

For example if the user enters BT4869A1, I want this to be included in postcodes, as postcode: BT4869A1- eventually adding place: "" and dates:[] for each new user.

Comment: I would go with what @Casey said. 

Just note * You cannot use .push unless the object your pushing to is an array. 
and **newuser** needs to be defined properly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have one more question if you could help, another array of objects I have is this:

   var waste =
    [
     { date : "13 December", collection: ["BT486AA1","BT171JR6","BT181JR3"] },

     { date: "14 December", collection: ["BT486AA1","BT171JR8"] }];

I want to search the collection array, to find which of the arrays has less that 3 objects in it, and the array with less than 3, I will then insert users input.